# Bootstrap - Is a good practice to set height to bootstrap's col, row, container, etc?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, standards

I'm starting to work with bootstrap after four years experience on html and css and I want to know if it is a good practice to set fixed height (px or %) to the elements

Comment: :-( :-(:-(:-(:-(:-( well it depends. but using paddings is more maintainable and predictable.

Comment: @JohnDevelops That new answer with fundamentals is very useful for me. Thanks you a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, I mainly use % as I find it more accurate given the variety of resolutions. Also there are a lot of solutions and tutorials on eights of elements for bootstrap initial formats. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is still just regular HTML and CSS, and as such can be edited/modified for your purposes. While there are common and accepted ways to use the Bootstrap framework, your given design and situation in any particular Bootstrap project will dictate what you do regarding heights etc.

I wouldn't call it bad practice or good practice, its what needs must :)